# split DataFrame into training and testing DataFrame using pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2038 length of DataFrame, which i want to split it into training and testing DataFrame using `PySpark`.

My DataFrame looks like this (`DataFrame Sample`) -

| Item | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 35 |
| 1 | 12 |
| 1 | 16 |
| 3 | 26 |

I want my DataFrame to Split like this

- Training DataFrame length - 2008 and
- Testing DataFrame length - 30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are requiring the exact number of sample in the training and testing dataset, functions like `randomSplit` or `sampleBy` that use fraction or weight is not suitable for your case. If you don't have any performance concern, one of the solutions is using the joining:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as func

df = spark\
    .createDataFrame([(str(i),) for i in range(2038)],
                     ['row_index'])
df.show(5, False)

+---------+
|row_index|
+---------+
|0        |
|1        |
|2        |
|3        |
|4        |
+---------+
```

Then you can use the joining directly:

```
train_df = df.limit(2000)
test_df = df.join(train_df, on='row_index', how='leftanti')
```

If you want to do randomization, just add:

```
train_df = df.orderBy(func.rand()).limit(2000)
```